# AQL - How to assign each document in a collection C a unique value from an array?

Tags: arangodb

How can I assign each document in a collection C a unique value from an array?

Let's say I create the array `let A = 1..count(C)`. How can I give each document in C a number from A, making sure each element of A is used only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's are unfortunately no Python-like iterators `enumerate()` and `zip()` in AQL, which would make this really easy and efficient. It is still possible however, but can be a costly operation (mainly memory-intense) for very large datasets, because all document keys need to be fetched and stored in memory:

```
LET arr = RANGE(1, LENGTH(C) * 2, 2)
LET docs = (FOR doc IN C RETURN doc._key)
FOR n IN 0..LENGTH(docs)-1
    UPDATE docs[n] WITH {number: arr[n]} IN test
    RETURN NEW
```

An array `arr` is generated (here: as many odd numbers as there are documents in the collection `C`), and a variable `docs` holds all document keys of `C`. A loop over the range 0..n with n = number of documents in `C` is used for a counter `n`. Then, the nth document key of `docs` is used to update a document with the nth number from the array `arr`.

If you want to assign `A = 1..LENGTH(C)`, then a slightly simpler query can be used:

```
LET docs = (FOR doc IN C RETURN doc._key)
FOR n IN 1..LENGTH(docs)
    UPDATE docs[n-1] WITH {number: n} IN test
    RETURN NEW
```

Comment: I couldn't find the iterator counter `n`, sometimes available as a second parameter like `for d, n in docs` (but not in AQL), and so I got stuck. And then the answer is as simple as a traditional for loop :) Good information about performance as well.

Comment: A second and third parameter is currently emitted by a [traversal FOR loop](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Operations/For.html) only. If you're creating a new collection and want auto-incrementing numbers as `_key`, check out the [keyOptions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/DataModeling/Collections/DatabaseMethods.html#create). Note that the `_key` will still be stored as string, but you can cast it to a number if necessary.